# How to specify that our app need IOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, minimum-requirements

Should we specify that at itunes connect?

Is there something on plist file?

Where exactly should we specify that?

I need to ensure that those with IOS 5 cannot download my app. I've heard only 3% of such people anyway.

Comment: Do a search on "Deployment Target".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by latest statistics released by Apple at their Key Note there are less then 5% of iOS active devices out there.

However, you do not specify the deployment target via itunesconnect. You do so in your xcode projects settings. From the list of TARGETS you choose your app and select "6.0" as your DEPLOYMENT TARGET. You also do the same for your PROJECT.

Comment: Actually isn't that strange that we specify things on 2 places? Which one is right? Targets or project?

Comment: One is more general than the other. A project can have many targets.

Comment: this is the only way to do this I guess, With this user of iOS below 6 still can download your app but they won't be able to run your app.